# PowerShell regex does not match near newline

Tags: regex, powershell, newline

I have an exe output in form

> ```
> Compression          : CCITT Group 4
> Width                : 3180
> ```

and try to extract `CCITT Group 4` to `$var` with PowerShell script

```
$var = [regex]::match($exeoutput,'Compression\s+:\s+([\w\s]+)(?=\n)').Groups[1].Value
```

The http://regexstorm.net/tester say, the regexp `Compression\s+:\s+([\w\s]+)(?=\n)` is correct but not PowerShell. PowerShell does not match. How can I write the regexp correctly?

Comment: I suspect you may have `\r\n` at the end. However, you do not need the lookahead at all since to get to the first newline you may use `.*` or `.+`.

Comment: Can you show [mcve]? It seems work just fine for me: https://tio.run/##XY29CoMwGAD3PMU3CDFYpNIOJSAVHEp3aQfjENoPFdSE/FTfPhWHtvTg1jutZjS2w2EIIcIFlXfaO8ihoKRUozZoba8m@MChLK9VBRejvIYjufdP18EfHA7ZaU9oQaKXNGutNtji0nA@Svfo4u9pR38uwiZ8Na7FLGyTsPici4lRlm4zW2dNepODx60awhs

Comment: @PetSerAl Strange, tio.run work correct, but my local script does not? Mistery?

Comment: @PetSerAl Than you all. I understand, I convert exe output as string  (`| Out-String`)and it earned.

Answer (score 2):

You want to get all text from some specific pattern till the end of the line. So, you do not even need the lookahead `(?=\n)`, just use `.+`, because `.` matches any char but a newline (LF) char:

```
$var = [regex]::match($exeoutput,'Compression\s+:\s+(.+)').Groups[1].Value
```

Or, you may use a `-match` operator and after the match is found access the captured value using `$matches[1]`:

```
$exeoutput -match 'Compression\s*:\s*(.+)'
$var = $matches[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

[Wiktor Stribiżew's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55080492/45375) simplifies your regex and shows you how to use PowerShell's 
`-match` operator as an alternative.

Your follow-up comment about piping to `Out-String` fixing your problem implies that your problem was that `$exeOutput` contained an *array* of lines rather than a *single, multiline* string.

This is indeed what happens when you **capture the output from a call to an external program (`*.exe`): PowerShell captures the stdout output lines as an *array of strings*** (the lines without their trailing newline).

As an alternative to converting array `$exeOutput` to a single, multiline string with `Out-String` (which, incidentally, is slow<sup>[1]</sup>), you can use a [`switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch) to operate on the array directly:

```
# Stores 'CCITT Group 4' in $var
$var = switch -regex ($exeOutput) { 'Compression\s+:\s+(.+)' { $Matches[1]; break } }
```

---

Alternatively, given the specific format of the lines in `$exeOutput`, you could leverage the 
[`ConvertFrom-StringData` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata), which can perform parsing the lines into key-value pairs for you, after having replaced the `:` separator with `=`:

```
$var = ($exeoutput -replace ':', '=' | ConvertFrom-StringData).Compression
```

---

<sup>[1] Use of a *cmdlet* is generally slower than using an *expression*; with a string array `$array` as input, you can achieve what `$array | Out-String` does more efficiently with `` $array -join "`n" ``, though note that `Out-String` also appends a *trailing* newline.</sup>